# awk maximum value of sequence of directories

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to find the maximum value in a directory suffix using awk.  The directories are named: dir.{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,etc}.  My best attempts keep returning "9" as the highest value, probably due to it listing after the 'teens.

The best I could do was to output the directory listing to a temporary file and run awk against that.  Is there a better way to find the greatest value in the suffix of dir.* with awk? I'd like to avoid creating a temporary file and just use 'ls -1' or similar input.

My directories of interest:

```
$ ls -1
dir.1
dir.10
dir.11
dir.12
dir.13
dir.14
dir.15
dir.2
dir.3
dir.4
dir.5
dir.6
dir.7
dir.8
dir.9
```

My awk command and output:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {max = 0} {if ($1>max) max=$1} END {print max}' DATA
dir.9
```

I'd like that result to be "dir.15".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compare two strings which are not numbers in awk, it compares them alphabetically. So you need to compare the actual numbers.

```
awk -F. '$NF+0>max{max=$NF;maxline=$0}END{print maxline}'
```

`-F.` sets the field separator to `.`, so that `$NF`, which is the value of the last field, will be the number following the last (or only) dot. We add 0 in case it is not a number. That will force it to be a number, converting any string which doesn't start with a digit into a 0.

There is no need to initialize max because as an uninitialized variable, it is numerically equivalent to 0.

Also, as @triplee notes in a comment, there is no need for a temporary file, since you can just pipe `ls -d` directly into the above `awk` line, assuming that no directory has a newline in its name:

```
ls -d | awk -F. '$NF+0>max{max=$NF;maxline=$0}END{print maxline}'
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick.  Clearly, I have a lot to learn.

Comment: There is no need for a temporary file, either.  Just `ls | awk` or even have Awk examine the filenames themselves.

Comment: @tripleee: good point. I didn't take note of the request to avoid the temporary file.